# ASP .NET - asp:Menu based on sitemap does not work in IE7?

Tags: asp.net, menu

I have a **asp:Menu** bound to a **Sitemap** on my sites **master** page:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2" 
     Orientation="Horizontal" 
     StaticDisplayLevels="2" 
     CssSelectorClass="PrettyMenu">
</asp:Menu>
```

The menu works really well on my development box with Firefox 3.5.  When I try to run the site within IE7 the menu does not respond at all.

Is there something related to the menu code that would cause this?

UPDATE2:

The issue appears to be related to the CSS Friendly Controls Adaptor.  Firefox is responsive but IE7 only shows the top tier of the menu and doesn't respond at all.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't respond? The dropdown menu? Care to show us the rendered HTML codes?

Comment: added as per your suggestion o.k.w.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with IIS 6.0 and IE8. The following Microsoft KB article talks about it. Don't know it applies in your case though:

http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B969612&x=5&y=10

Comment: not sure if this KB relates directly - but there is something definitely not right.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters something similar:

I had to remove the CSS Friendly (browser) files from the project and all the menu issues went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, editing CSSFriendlyAdapters.Browser (located in App_Browsers folder )solved my problem. It was like this, you should remove some elements:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.MenuAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>

  <browser id="W3C_Validator" parentID="default">
    <identification>
      <userAgent match="^W3C_Validator" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="browser"              value="W3C Validator" />
      <capability name="ecmaScriptVersion"    value="1.2" />
      <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCss"          value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
      <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
      <capability name="tagWriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
      <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```